# Would two hours between landing in SFO, and flying to Vegas be enough? I have to claim and recheck the baggage

Tags: airport-transfer, sfo

I just learned that I have to claim and recheck my baggage in SFO. Would 2 hours be enough to do that?

Comment: Are you arriving in SFO from overseas? What airlines are you flying with and is it a single ticket?

Answer (score 10):

If both flights are on a single ticket and you have to do this just because you are arriving from overseas, then:

- “recheck” is actually just drop your luggage at a counter just after you exit customs
- Your bags are already tagged to the final destination, so there’s virtually no waiting there, you just put your bags on the conveyor belt and off you go
- You still have to go through passport control, wait for your bags, eventually go to your new terminal if different, and go through security.
- 2 hours should be enough (airlines like to think that nowadays this can be done in a lot less time), but can vary a lot depending on your citizenship/visa status, how busy the airport is on that date at that time, your status, etc.
- If you miss your flight because of this the airline will rebook you on the next one. It’s a good idea to check when that is.

Again, that is in the case the two flights are on a single ticket.

If the two flights are ticketed separately then you have to go to check-in for your second flight, and have to do that before the check-in deadline (details vary but often 40 to 60 minutes before departure). This makes things a lot tighter even if there are no delays, and impossible if anything goes wrong.

And in that situation in many cases your second ticket may just be cancelled (including the return flight, if any) because you didn’t show up in time, so you may have to buy a new ticket on the spot, at usually much more expensive last minute prices. I would very very strongly advise against that option.